# How do you run a tar command to backup a folder inside a docker container to the host?

Tags: docker, tar

My docker container has a directory that I want to periodically backup to the host.

I would think the command would be something like this:

```sh
docker-compose exec SERVICE_NAME tar -czf - -C /dir/to/backup . > backup.tar.gz
```

This should create a file called `backup.tar.gz` on the host.

Instead, `tar` detects that the output appears to be going to a terminal, and errors out:

```sh
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

As far as I can tell, there's no `--force`, or anything like that for the `tar` command.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) procedure in the Docker documentation's discussion of named volumes?  (Which involves running a new container bind-mounting the host directory and also mounting the volume you want to back up.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess both ways are possible. Good to know there's an alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways:

1. You can tell docker compose to not allocate a pty using the `-T` option.

   Example:

   ```sh
   docker-compose exec -T SERVICE_NAME tar -czf - -C /dir/to/backup . > backup.tar.gz
   ```

   The presence of a pty is how most programs, including tar, detect whether or not they are running in a terminal or attached to a pipe.
2. You can trick tar into writing output into a terminal by using `/dev/stdout` in place of `-`.

   Example:

   ```
   $ tar -czf /dev/stdout etc/
   ```

   This makes tar write the archive to standard out. Do keep in mind that this restriction [exists for a reason](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/can-cat-ing-a-file-be-a-potential-security-risk).